# Using Three.js (r78), how to transition line material color between two values along a path?

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

I thought I understood this [example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lines_colors), but my attempt at applying this to my code produces solid black lines. Could someone please help me understand why this might not be working?

```
function(ptArray) {
  var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry(),
      material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        linewidth: 4,
        vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
      }),
      linePositions = new Float32Array(pts),
      lineColors = new Float32Array(pts),
      visible = new Float32Array(pts / 3);

  visible.fill(1.0);

  for (var p = 0; p < pts; p ++) {
    linePositions[p] = ptArray[p];
    lineColors[p] = new THREE.Color(0xffffff).setHSL(p/pts, 1.0, 0.5);
  }

  geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(linePositions, 3));
  geometry.addAttribute('vertColor', new THREE.BufferAttribute(lineColors, 3));
  geometry.addAttribute('visible', new THREE.BufferAttribute(visible, 1));

  scene.add(new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, material);
}
```

Comment: do you have lights in your scene? oh and try to name the attribute `color` not `vertColor`

Comment: I do have lights in the scene. Is there a reason not to "veryColor"?

Comment: the shader does not know what to do with custom attributes - it would have to guess what to do with the "vertColor" which is just an array of numbers without any information if it came from THREE.Color object or THREE.Vector3 or you filled it by hand  take look at http://threejs.org/examples/?q=buffer#webgl_buffergeometry_lines where buffer geometry is used for colored line